# flex: undefined reference to `yywrap' only when compiling/linking separately

Tags: c, flex-lexer

I've been learning to use Flex (the lexical analyser) and I've been compiling with the following command:

`gcc -lfl -o test lex.yy.c`

and all is well. However, I want to link it with other files, so I compile and link it separately with

`gcc -c lex.yy.c`

followed by

`gcc -lfl -o test lex.yy.o`

but gcc tells me that there is an undefined reference to `yywrap()`. So, what's going on here?

I'm using Flex 2.5.35, gcc 4.7.2 and ld 2.22

Comment: did you try to add `-lfl` at the end instead of beginning?

Comment: okay, i will post that as answer.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

add `-lfl` at the end instead of beginning.

Answer (score 4):

Use `gcc lex.yy.c -ll`. Otherwise it will yield an undefined reference to `yywrap`.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, if you don't want to use the library, just `#define yywrap()` 1 in your .l file, or provide a `yywrap()` method that returns 1.

It's documented.

Answer (score 1):

My solution was:

sudo apt-get install flex

Comment: Please explain how you had already generated a lex.yy.c file without having flex already installed.

Answer (score 1):

I created a file addon.c

```
int yywrap (void )
{
    return 1;
}
```

and added it to the target.